# First time setting up a cron job

Tags: php, cron

I'm totally new to cron jobs.

1. How do I set up a cron job that runs a PHP function once per day, at midnight?
2. What filetype does the cron job file need?

I have only FTP access to my website so I'm not the administrator on the server. I have Googled and read related questions here on Stack Overflow, without any results.

Comment: No. I have only access to phpMyAdmin and FTP. The control panel is only for administrate my subscription, adding new subdomains, email addresses for my domains and so on.

Comment: Close? May be better suited for serverfault...

Comment: Close?! O.o I want to know how I'm setting up cron jobs. I don't know how and I want help to how I begin.

Answer (score 2):

Cron tabs (the files created, usually with the `crontab` utility, listing your cron jobs) are saved in a system folder outside your reach if you don't have shell access. They don't have a filetype or extension. They are named after the Unix/Linux username. On Darwin/Mac OS X they are located in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs/`. Without shell access or a cPanel extension (usually in the Adanced section), you're out of luck.

Comment: Many thanks for your correct answer, dda! I'll call the support for the web hotel as soon as they opens :)

Answer (score 0):

You either need access to the cpanel or a terminal (SSH) in order to set up a cron job.

If you are using cpanel, you can just read these instructions to add a job

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm

Where, the command is the actual linux command being executed.

If you have shell access to the server (not FTP) you can set up a job by running this command

```
crontab cron.txt
```

where the contents of the `cron.txt` are something like this

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/mydir/project/file.php
```

Where the starts imply the times the job runs (in this case every minute)

You can search for online crontab makers which will help you find the syntax for the time you need to execute your command but you can't do this with just FTP and PHPMyAdmin access.